# How to know that user doesn't touch keyboard?

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, swift2

I have `UISearchController` and `UISearchBar` in it. I want to make a call of function after 3 second when user doesn't touch the keyboard (when user finished write text on keyboard). I searched this information, but I didn't find any information. How can I make it?

Comment: use a timer which gets reset on every key touch, if the timer runs out the user has not touched a key in the last 3 seconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `searchBar textDidChange` method by starting a timer and delaying the search method every time the searchText changes :

Objective-c :

```
-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
[searchDelayer invalidate];
searchDelayer=nil;
searchDelayer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3
                                                 target:self
                                               selector:@selector(doDelayedSearch:)
                                               userInfo:searchText
                                                repeats:NO];
}

-(void)doDelayedSearch:(NSTimer *)t
{
assert(t == searchDelayer);
[self request:searchDelayer.userInfo]; // your search method
searchDelayer = nil;
}
```

Don't forget to add   `NSTimer *searchDelayer` in your `.h` file.

Swift :

```
var searchDelayer: NSTimer

override func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
searchDelayer.invalidate()
searchDelayer = nil
searchDelayer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(3, target: self, selector: "doDelayedSearch", userInfo: searchText, repeats: false)
}

func doDelayedSearch(t: NSTimer) {
assert(t == searchDelayer)
self.request(searchDelayer.userInfo)
searchDelayer = nil
}
```